# How to optimize codes present in if, else if and else conditions

Tags: r

Looking by the code, you see I use `if`, `else if`, and `else` conditions. Note that some codes are very similar for both conditions, what changes, in general, between the conditions are the following lines: `group_by` from the `med` , `inner_join` from the first `SPV` and `filter` from the second `SPV`. Is there any way to optimize this code so that I don't need to repeat similar codes under both conditions?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- structure(
  list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-06-23","2021-06-24","2021-06-30","2021-07-01"),
       DTT= c("Hol","Hol","Hol",0),
       Week= c("Wednesday","Thursday","Wednesday","Thursday"),
       Category = c("ABC","FDE","ABC","FDE"),
       DR1 = c(4,1,1,2),
       DR01 = c(4,1,2,3), DR02= c(4,2,0,2),DR03= c(9,5,0,1),
       DR04 = c(5,4,3,2),DR05 = c(5,4,0,2)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

dmda<-"2021-07-01"
CategoryChosse<-"FDE"
DTest<-"0"
Wk<-"Thursday"

Dx<-subset(df1,df1$date2<df1$date1)

x<-Dx %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))

x<-cbind(Dx, setNames(Dx$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))

PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DTT, DR1, ends_with("PV"))


if(any(PV$DTT == DTest & PV$Week== Wk, na.rm = TRUE)) {
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week,DTT) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week','DTT')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse, DTT==DTest)  
  
} 

else if(!(any(PV$DTT == DTest & PV$Week== Wk, na.rm = TRUE))) {
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda)  
  
} 

else {
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  
  SPV <- df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse)
}
```

Comment: Please don't put code like `rm(list = ls())` in your question. No one wants to accidentally run that while trying to help and lose their work.

Comment: The error is the line breaks between the end of your `if(){}` and the `else if{}` and `else{}`. When running lines through the R console, the interpreter will think you are done as soon as it gets to a valid line end, which happens at the end of an `if()` statement unless there is an `else` on the same line. Change `} <<line break>> else {` to `} else { <<linebreak>>` and your code will run fine.

Comment: Gregor, I have a question if you can answer it. Looking by the code, you see I use `if`, `else if`, and `else`. Note that some codes are very similar for both conditions, what changes, in general, between the conditions are the following lines: `group_by` from the `med` , `inner_join` from the first `SPV` and `filter` from the second `SPV`. Is there any way to optimize this code so that I don't need to repeat similar codes under both conditions?

Comment: Just as an FYI (because this confused me a lot once), the line breaks before `else` are okay *if it's within a curly braced expression*, like inside a function definition. I once thought I had caught a bug in the code of some R package because there was a linebreak before the `else`, but it was inside a function definition so it didn't matter. (Though I do think good practice would be to write code that works regardless of whether it's in a function or not.)

Comment: For optimizing, it in the first statement where you create `med`, it seems like the only difference is what cols to group by. So you could isolate out the grouping bit, say `group_cols = if(any(PV$DTT == DTest & PV$Week== Wk, na.rm = TRUE)) {c("Category", "Week")} else {"Category"}` and then `group_by(across(all_of(group_cols)))` to have a single definition of `med` and similarly use that `group_cols` variable in the join.

Comment: And it's not clear to me that the final `else{}` will ever get run? Don't you essentially have `if(X) {...} else if(!X) {...} else{...}`. But either `X` or `!X` will always be true, so the final `else{}` is pointless.

Comment: You are right. Just to explain better, the first condition is if you have `PV$DTT == DTest & PV$Week== Wk`. The second condition is if I don't have `PV$DTT == DTest & PV$Week== Wk`. And the third condition is if I don't have `PV$DTT == DTest` , but I have `PV$Week== Wk` and `PV$Category==CategoryChosse`.

Comment: Gregor, what do you think if I change this question about optimization of conditions, so you can insert as answer, what do you think?

Comment: Sure. Since no one's answered yet, no harm done.

Comment: Just following up on your conditions: as coded, your first `if()` is if you have any row where `PV$DTT == DTest & PV$Week== Wk`. Your `else if()` is if you don't have any row where `PV$DTT == DTest & PV$Week== Wk`. Your final `else{}` will never be reached because the second condition is the complement of the first condition. I can't tell from your code/comments what your intention is. I'd suggest making a little truth table and testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up your code, make sure to include `else` statements on the same line as the `}` of the preceding `if()`.

Streamlining, don't use an `else` if it is impossible to get. Call

```
X <- any(PV$DTT == DTest & PV$Week== Wk, na.rm = TRUE)
```

`X` is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Your code then reads

```
if(X) {
  ...
} else if(!X) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

The final `else` will never be reached, because either `X` or `!X` will be true.

You can also avoid repetition by using variables, e.g., at a glance the difference between the `if` and the `else if` are the grouping columns and the join columns. So instead of rewriting code blocks, make those elements dynamic. Something like this (untested):

```
group_cols <-
  if(any(PV$DTT == DTest & PV$Week== Wk, na.rm = TRUE)) {
    c("Category", "Week", "DTT")
  } else {
    "Category"
  } 

med <- PV %>%
  group_by(across(all_of(group_cols))) %>%
  summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))

SPV <- df1 %>%
  inner_join(med, by = group_cols) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
  select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())

SPV <- SPV %>% filter(date2 == dmda)

if("Category" %in% group_cols) {
  SPV = SPV %>% filter(Category == CategoryChosse, DTT==DTest) 
}
```